# What are the advantages of moving to an Azure database server then installing it directly

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

I am currently using a database from an installed instance on my web server in a VM on Azure.  I was thinking about moving it to an actual Azure Database so I could load balance the web server.  Does the Azure database work the same way as a straight install?  Will it cost more or the same since I am just moving to a new server?  Basically looking for advantages and disadvantages.  I am familiar with SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL offers many advantages over an installed version specifically around availability, scalability, and lower maintenance. Here are a few things to consider:

1. There are cost savings as well but that also depends on the features you select, size of the databases, and obviously quantity of them. Geo-replication can also be a factor in the costs. You can find more about pricing [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/).
2. There are also some feature limitations as not 100% of the same features are available compared to an installed version. You can read about the differences [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/996.comparison-of-sql-server-with-azure-sql-database.aspx) and decide for yourself if there are any deal breakers.
3. New features ARE being rolled into the SQL as a Service platform rapidly and you get them sooner than waiting for the next version of SQL being released.

If you can make the jump, I'd highly recommend it for the scalability, less maintenance, and cost savings that you're likely to get.

Comment: It seems to be I would have to actually pay for a database.  Having an installed instance I didnt.